# agora.io react-native setEnableSpeakerphone is taking too much time

Tags: react-native, agora.io, speaker

"react-native": "0.61.5"
"react-native-agora": "^3.4.6",
Android 11

using react native agoraio RtcEngine for audio only calls, setEnableSpeakerphone has now started taking about 2-3 seconds, and causing trouble for users.
on Android studio, I can see this warning being logged.

*2021-10-09 21:28:54.837 20698-23440/com.owwll W/BpBinder: Slow Binder: BpBinder transact took 1288ms, interface=android.media.IAudioService, code=9 oneway=false*

This is majorly on android, some of iOS users has also reported it.

Comment: Have you tried using the latest version of the SDK (v3.5.0)?

Comment: yes tried with 3.5.0 but no luck, same results.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest version ([v3.5.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-agora) at the time of writing) of the SDK.

Comment: yes tried with 3.5.0 but no luck, same results.

Comment: I'd suggest opening a support ticket.

Comment: opening a ticket did nt help either, seems like these guys have no idea :P